# UC3842 IC not working

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, pwm, voltage-measurement

I have a simple UC3842 IC and I want to test that. First I used the open loop circuit from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3842.pdf?ts=1692538321089&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUC3842) but it didn't work therefore I went through the datasheet again and found from the schematic that if I simply power up the IC then I would able to get a 5V at the output of the VREF pin. I removed all the components and make a simple schematic by just powering the IC.

Upon testing found that I was getting zero volts on all the pins. What's wrong with it? Kindly help me figure this out. I also tested a 3843 IC and it did the same. Both the ICs cant be damaged. Furthermore for the input of UC3843 I used 7.9V as input and for UC3842 I used 15.6V as input. Two capacitors of 0.1u were connected from Vcc and Vref to the grounds. A test image of the UC3842 is shown:
[image]

The test circuit used earlier:
[image]

I used all the values the same as shown here except the C-R values(0.1u and 22k used) and the potentiometer at the emitter 10k used instead of 5k. That shouldn't make any difference at all.

Comment: The device won’t do much without RT/CT as this sets the oscillator frequency. Try 1nF/15kohm. The test circuit should work - the isense adjust should be set to 0V to begin with. You could omit the transistor and 5K pot and tie isense to 0V. Less parts = less potential for mistakes. If you can’t get the test circuit working, you’re doing something wrong.

Comment: No luck the IC seems to be dead. It's giving no voltages at any other pins. Ref voltage is zero so no ocsillation can be done

Comment: You saw where the minimum supply starting is 9 and 17.5V respectively, not 7.9 and 15.6, right?

Comment: There are two models one have a greater UVLO than the other. The UVLO on and off voltage is 16 and 10V respectively. Does that mean that my ic will work above 16V or it works between 10-16? Just have this confusion.

Comment: It means to guarantee operation, you must apply voltages higher than these, at least initially. Operation continues until UVLO (falling) threshold.

Comment: @TimWilliams thankyou the problem has been solved. It was the same problem of voltage. i applied 17V at it worked. But I have an ofset in the Isense pin when I tried the circuit given above. I somehow adjusted my ramp signal to get a full dutycycle pwm but I want to completely eliminate that. Because the comparing wount be then completely with a ramp. Shall I add a capacitor in series to remove ofset and then put it to the potentiometer? Would that create any problem for me or not?

Comment: I don't understand.  `ISENSE` takes an input 0...1V.  The test circuit uses the RtCt ramp to supply this (via emitter follower).  Which will normally be around 3V, so the pot should be set around 30%. Then adjust the EA pot to vary output PWM. It may not go all the way to 0 or 100%, depending on how things work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: UC384x UVLO characteristics]

UVLO (under-voltage lock-out) is a function which disables the chip below some supply voltage, and enables it above a threshold.

A hysteresis threshold is used, so that when the device turns on, its increased current draw does not immediately bring it under the threshold and halt operation.  It remains on down to a lower threshold.

For initial turn-on / startup, V<sub>CC</sub> must be raised above at least 7.8V (UC3843/5) for some parts to turn on, and at most 9V for any part to turn on.  Likewise 14.5-17.5V for UC3842/4.

Operation can continue as low as 9-11.5V (3842/4) or 7-8.2V (3843/5).

The range is due to manufacturing variance: the thresholds are not set precisely, but vary some due to the fabrication process.  To guarantee operation of any given device, supply at least VCC<sub>ON</sub> max initially, and at least VCC<sub>OFF</sub> max after startup.  To ensure shut-down, apply VCC<sub>OFF</sub> min or less.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an UC3843 working very "well" ...

[image]

And here is your circuit ... with some adjustments (V1 = 12 V).

[image]

Comment: Which simulator have you used?

Comment: Made with free https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110

Comment: I have made the same circuit with Pspice from TI and it isnt giving me these result

Comment: Huh, your -2 model at least seems to be erroneous -- it's guaranteed not to start at 12V.

Comment: Start working at 12 V until 28 V ... in datasheet (D package, ok there are some).

Comment: It's not package; none in the family have a 12V UVLO threshold. UC384x -3/-5 start at 7.8-9V, -2/-4 at 14.5-17.5V (TI datasheet). A threshold of 16 rising / 10 falling would be pretty reasonable choices, but it's baffling that they apparently chose <12 (rising) here. Or, UVLO isn't modeled at all. Since MicroCap is unsupported, it's not very useful to complain about errors, but we can draw one moral: always check SPICE models for validity of any and all functions, and decide whether those functions (or lack thereof) affect a given application.

Comment: UC3843/5 Uvlo on=7.8--9 V and Uvlo off=7--8.2 V (???). So 12 V is "ok".